# About Sonicwall lifecycle

Tags: networking, sonicwall, lifecycle

I'm imvestigating about a Sonicwall UMT appliance, I'm intersted in the TZ215 Wireless but I just read that model is in LTB ([Last Time Buy](http://o-www.sonicwall.com/us/support/Product_Lifecycle.html)) phase.

Does anybody knows how many years could this mean until the end of life?
I just want to be sure if worth it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This question probably isn't best on ServerFault but with your vendor.  They have a much better idea of how often the products are removed and are often told when to stop selling them.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear from the description that the LTB cycle is variable, dependent on multiple factors and completely at the discretion of SonicWall, so I don't see how anyone here can give you a definitive answer.

> Last Time Buy (LTB)
>
> Last Time Buy (LTB) is advanced notification to
>   SonicWALL customers and partners that SonicWALL intends to start the
>   end of life process. The duration of this phase is variable and
>   depends on numerous factors including material availability, SonicWALL
>   and channel inventory and end-user demand. Last Time Buy is
>   informational only. Products in this phase are active.